# Why does InDesign lose all keyboard ability if a scriptUI palette is open?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, adobe-scriptui

Salvete!  I have a simple InDesign script to display a palette window.  Problem is, when I display this window, or any other scriptui palette, InDesign loses all keyboard focus - I just can't type anything.  It's as if the script palette eats all my keyboard input.

Here is the most simple script:

```
#targetengine session;    //I have tried without this line, too.
var PaletteWindow = new Window('palette', "Test");
PaletteWindow.show();
```

Am I missing something?  Has anyone else seen this problem?
I am using InDesign CS4 on XP Pro SP3; Dell Precision T3400 with Core Duo; 4mb of RAM.

Here is the link to my post at InDesignSecrets:
http://indesignsecrets.com/forum/indesign-add-ons-scripts-scripting-and-plug-ins/scriptui-palette-breaks-keyboard#p8419

Comment: Hello?  Is there anybody out there?

Comment: This post has been here now for 4 months, and nobody has even tried to answer.  I still have the same problem.  I'v posted on different forums (even InDesignSecrets) all to no avail.  If anyone even has a clue, please hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I figured I could answer my own question after four months.  This link is to a thread with the same problem where the palettes steal keyboard focus.  It does not contain a definitive solution, but does offer a workaround:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/288782?start=0&tstart=0

Here is another workaround:
Since the palette is supposed to "do something" and then return focus to IND, then add:

```
app.activate();
```

to the function call for the button.  That way, after you push the button, you can work normally in IND.

This works fine, except that *anytime* you move the mouse over the palette, it sets focus to the application.  This solution is a workaround for CS4.

**[update]**
Now I am using CS5, and I find that it is no longer necessary to do this.  It seems the problem was a bug in the CS4 UI scripting interface.